# How do you differentiate $\frac{1}{n^x}$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do you differentiate $\frac{1}{n^x}$

Do you have to use chain rule?

Comment: $\frac d {dx} e^{-x\ln n}=-\ln n \frac 1 {n^{x}}$.

Comment: Let $n>0.$ An alternative method (not my preferred) is to let $y=\dfrac1{n^x}$ so that $\ln y=-x\ln n;$ then differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, chain rule is part of it. Write
$$\frac1{n^x}=n^{-x}=e^{-x\ln n}$$
and then differentiate w.r.t. $x$.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my uni (and even school) we were not only taught that $(\mathrm e^x)' = (\mathrm e^x)$, but also more general
$$
(a^x)' = a^x\cdot\log a \tag{1}.
$$
If you are allowed to use $(1)$, then no need for the chain rule, just notice that $\frac{1}{n^x} = \left(\frac1n\right)^x$ so here $a = \frac1n$.